# Prettier format on save not working in CSS or HTML files

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I recently installed prettier (V9.0.0) in VS Code and enabled format on save.

This is working in CSS files but doesn't work in JS or HTML files. Has anyone had this problem and fixed it?

Not sure what other context to provide but happy to provide anything else that might be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this in your vscode's settings.json,

```
"[scss]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed [in the past](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108447).
Few things you can try:

- set prettier as the **Default Formatter** in Settings .
  File -> Preferences -> Settings (for Windows)
  Code -> Preferences -> Settings (for Mac).
  Search for "Default Formatter".
- You can also [set default Formatter per language](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108447#issuecomment-733176851)

Comment: Fixed it thanks a bunch sorry for asking asking

Answer (score 1):

Open the command palette : command + shift + p (Mac)
tape : "Preferences : open User Settings (JSON)"
add the following line to the json file :

```
"[css]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me only html formatting did not work. I just type this in settings:

```
@id:editor.defaultFormatter @lang:html formatter
```

and there in list you need to choose prettier.

Comment: please double check that my edit is correct (if not, please fix it)